# Choosing action based on maximum value among multiple variables

Tags: netlogo

My turtles have calculate several variables each tick: `gain-stay`, `gain-move`, `gain-grow`, `gain-shrink`. I would like them to either stay, move, grow or shrink according to whichever of those variables had the highest value. I have, procedures called `to stay`, `to move`, etc.

For simplicity, if several variables are tied for the maximum value, I don't care which of their strategy is taken. If it would be easier to name the variables just `shrink`, `stay`, etc., that's just fine.

It seems like I have two steps to solve:

1. Extract the *name* of the variable having the maximum value.
2. Run the strategy indicated by that name. I think this would use `runresult` and am less stumped by it than by the first step.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: In general, you should try something and show us what you've tried. However, this is actually a tricky problem so I can understand why you'd have difficult working out an approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code selects the best strategy by comparing the maximum value found with the contents of each variable and constructing a list of names of all the matches. It then randomly selects one of the names. This is a complete program, you can open a new model and just copy it in to see what happens.

```
turtles-own [s1 s2 s3 s4]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set s1 random 10
    set s2 random 10
    set s3 random 10
    set s4 random 10
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles
  [ type "my values are " type s1 type s2 type s3 print s4
    let maxval max (list s1 s2 s3 s4)
    let strategy-list []
    if maxval = s1 [set strategy-list fput "s1" strategy-list]
    if maxval = s2 [set strategy-list fput "s2" strategy-list]
    if maxval = s3 [set strategy-list fput "s3" strategy-list]
    if maxval = s4 [set strategy-list fput "s4" strategy-list]
    let chosen one-of strategy-list
    run (word "do-" chosen)            
  ]
  tick
end

to do-s1
  print "I chose s1"
end

to do-s2
  print "I chose s2"
end

to do-s3
  print "I chose s3"
end

to do-s4
  print "I chose s4"
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  I would not in a thousand years have thought of making a list of one item as an intermediate step.

Comment: It's not always a one item list - if there's two (or more) strategies that have the maximum score then both will appear in the list and the strategy pursued will be randomly selected from those. This is why I have used a list rather than simply using nested ifelse and going to the first strategy with the maximum score.